# Distribution of an integral of normalised Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a question regarding the distribution of $\int_{\lambda}^{1} \frac{W(s)}{\sqrt{s}}ds$. Is this well defined for $\lambda=0$ and is there an obvious distribution it is equivalent to?

Comment: 1) Yes, it's well-defined since $\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |W_s|<\infty$ pointwise and $\int_0^1 s^{-1/2}<\infty$. 2) It's Gaussian.